# Question on certain terminologies in CMOS Technologies

Tags: circuit-design, inverter, cmos

So, when someone says a CMOS inverter (or any CMOS component) is "weaker" or "stronger". Is "weaker" referring to smaller Width and higher resistance (or the reverse; assume constant L)?

As an example:
[image]

Comment: I interpret stronger as lower output impedance (lower impedance in the transistors connecting output to positive or negative rail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DKNguyen correctly interprets stronger CMOS components as having comparatively lower output impedance. When talking about transistor sizing, your are right that characterization of stronger devices can be translated into 'having greater widths'. But notice that the excerpt cited discusses "**minimum-sized devices**" used in the transmission gates and how to make the transistors of a particular inverter "even weaker". With a **minimum-size** transistor you cannot decrease the transistor width, so weakening of this component can only be "*accomplished by making their channel-lengths larger than minimum*". In practical design, it is important to know what parameters can be varied and what are the limits of their values. In the following sentence, the text of your citation specifies the power dissipation solution for the clock distribution network and how it is achieved with the transistor sizing.